# Movie about a boy who enters a fantasy world from a basement

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a late 80s/Early 90s fantasy film:

- Boy is given necklace with green gem from grandfather.
- The necklace opens a portal to a fantasy world in the basement. I believe the gem creates a door which the boy goes through. He is unable to return until the task he is given is completed. There may have been a small word-based ritual that activated the gem.
- Boy befriends frog creature.
- Large Zeus-like giant king on throne.
- Targeted towards Children.
- Color.
- Last remember watching in the late 90s.
- It is not Never-ending story, Storybook, or PageMaster.

Anyone have any ideas? I have already gone through all of the "80s/90s Fantasy/sci-fi" lists on IMDB, and have searched every combination of search terms on Google.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: For example, was this live-action or animated? Was the boy caucasian? Dd the necklace just transport him at will or was there a ritual or command words?

Comment: Do you remember the task he was given? And did you watch it in English?

Comment: I remember the same movie and I cannot find the right answer as to if it's a movie or a show. I also recall the task had to be done in one wp or part of movie by the end of an eclipse, and a witch brewing a spell with her dad's talking head in a sack hanging on the wall of a cave.

Comment: @Hazel siwel - I recommend that you post your own story-ID question by clicking on the 'Ask Question' near the top-right corner of the page. A new question is likely to generate more interest than an old one that's been topped. You can include a link to this question in your own question if you like.

Answer (score 2):

[The Lost Medallion: The Adventures of Billy Stone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1390539/) (2013)?

> A man who stops into a foster home to drop off some donations tells the kids a story about two teenage friends who uncover a long-lost medallion that transports them back in time.

Comment: This can't possibly be the right movie assuming that FromThe90s (OP) really did last see it "in the late 90s".

Answer (score 0):

And maybe "House II: The Second Story" (1987) ? Somebody gave an answer on the other forum.

Comment: I very much doubt that _[House II: The Second Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_II:_The_Second_Story)_ is the correct answer. While there are some elements in common with the description, the main character is a man, not a boy, there's no necklace (although there is a crystal skull), there's no frog creature (although there is a dog/caterpillar hybrid), and it's a horror movie; a horror comedy, sure, but not really something aimed at children.

Comment: Incidentally, since you mentioned that someone gave this as an answer on the "other forum," it'd be helpful to provide a link to that other question, so that we can tell whether it was posted by the same querent as the one who posted this question, or if the descriptions are otherwise similar enough to suggest that both questions are asking about the same film. Without being able to check the other question, we also have no way of knowing whether this answer was indicated to be the correct answer to that other question or not.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer and what details to add in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).

Answer (score -1):

I never watched it myself but I remember seeing a trailer years ago from something called [*The Spiderwick Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles_(film)). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this answer matches what they're looking for?

Comment: You can see a sort of short sidekick here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plovZLxlpGk

Comment: Not this one. This is a bit newer than the movie I am looking for,

Comment: While *Spiderwick* does have a magic stone (it's a seeing stone though, not a gem), and is targeted to children, and maybe at a longish stretch you could confuse Thimbletack the Boggart for a frog thing, it doesn't really match anything else described here.