# Cartoon/animation with this green gem/rock thing that they used to summon creatures

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was a cartoon/animation where there were 3 main characters and there was this green gem/rock thing that they used to summon creatures. The cartoon started with a kid who received a necklace from his grandfather and there was a green gem in the middle. Then when he was running during a race he was magically sucked into the rock.

Comment: Is [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190986/movie-about-a-boy-who-enters-a-fantasy-world-from-a-basement) asking about the same story?  Not suggesting it as a dupe since it doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Im trying to find the name of the cartoon

Comment: Yes its about the same story

Comment: Based on OP's comment on the answer, this is yet another duplicate of [Anime with gems that can summon beasts to fight for the user, one is a purple turtle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the relatively thin details in the question, this *might* be [*Magi-Nation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series)) ([IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001475/)).

As can be seen in [this previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221349/101407), the hero (Tony) has a green gem that transports him.  According to the Wikipedia entry, it was indeed given to him by his grandfather.

[image: Tony running with his gem activating]

In the Moonlands he teams up with 2 other youth (Edyn and Strag) to prevent the Big Bad Agram from being freed.  The team can summon Dream Creatures using their gems.

[image: Heroes of Magi-Nation with their Dream Creatures]

Comment: Thank you so much i had been searching for that name for quite a while

Comment: @Whatever Please don't forget to click on the checkmark at the top left corner of the answer to indicate it is correct, so future visitors will know the question has a correct answer.

Comment: I'm honestly astounded at how frequently we get ID questions that turn out to be *Magi-Nation*. It's somehow popular enough to have had a substantial audience, but also obscure enough that they all forgot its name.